# Randomising 2 CSV files

Tags: python, csv, random, shuffle

I want to randomise two CSV files simultaneously using python as 1 to 1 functions ie.

```
File1.csv.                  File2.csv
1.                                A
2.                                B
3.                                C
4.                                D
5.                                E
```

Output will be

```
File1.csv.                 File2.csv
4.                               D
1.                               A
3.                               C
5.                               E
2.                               B
```

Comment: Is there only one column in the csv file? Can you be more precise and describe more on your problem?

Comment: There are more than one columns in my CSV file.There are two different CSV files that are related to each other.So if any changes is made in one CSV I want them to be reflected to the other as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since csv files are static flat files, you can not directly shuffle them. What you need is to read both files as pd Dataframes, shuffle them both and then write them in csvs. Here is the code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('datafile1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('datafile2.csv')

# reset the index by row numbers, so that both dataframe has identical index
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

#Shuffle the rows
df1 = df1.sample(frac=1) # frac says what fraction of rows shall be returned, 1 means return all rows. This will ensure that all rows are shuffled randomly 
df2 = df2.loc[df1.index] # Since I am using index of df1 to order df2, I am ensuring same order 

# Put back the original indes
df1.set_index('index',drop=True, inplace=True)
df2.set_index('index',drop=True, inplace=True)

# Write back to original files
df1.to_csv('datafile1.csv')
df2.to_csv('datafile2.csv')
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `numpy.random.shuffle` [wiki](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html)
i.g:

```
import numpy as np

letters = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
np.random.shuffle(letters)
print(letters)
np.random.shuffle(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

the output is here:

```
['A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'D']
[2, 6, 4, 1, 5, 3]
```